# Drawing Hexagon grid in Cocos 2d-x

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-x, hexagonal-tiles

So I'm about to create an Hexagon grid game in `Cocos2D-X`. I need it to be responsive to touches and I'm going to trigger some animations and actions when the user touches an hexagon.

I was wondering which is the better approach to achieve this.
Using the `CCTMXTiledMap` to create the hex tiled map, or drawing the hexagon grid by myself?

In the custom drawing solution, `CCDrawNode` is the better way to draw my hexagons?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: "better" being defined as .. ? It's a subjective question and depends on your goals, requirements and skills. CCTMXTiledMap works out of the box, but it's less flexible and custom drawing could be more efficient. Could be meaning: you'd have to test and compare that.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I mean the most appropriate. I am not going to display any characters or sprites on the hexagon grid, just use it for user interaction. And also I haven't used the CCDrawNode yet, so I don't know if it's going to be easy to use it, or get  really complicated to draw the hexagon with it.

Comment: Well then start with tilemap, see what it can do for you (cocos2d-iphone version at least has methods to determine on which hex field a touch is located). Custom solutions require you to do the hex layout (not too difficult) and hex touch detection (not too simple). Amits game programming guide to the rescue: http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/

Comment: Ok, I'll start with that and see how it goes, thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using `CCDrawNode` to drawn the hexagon myself, this way I have the desired hexagonal touch space, and I don't have to make any extra calculations to check witch hexagon was touched.

Here's the algorithm:

```
Hexagon::Hexagon(float hexagonWidth, float hexagonHeight, Color4F fillColor)
{
    float width = hexagonWidth;
    float height = hexagonHeight;

    _drawNode = CCDrawNode::create();
    Point vertices[6] = {
        Point( 0.f, height/2 ),
        Point( width*1/4, height ),
        Point( width*3/4, height ),
        Point( width, height/2 ),
        Point( width*3/4, 0.f ),
        Point( width*1/4, 0.f )
    };

    Color4F borderColor = {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    _drawNode->drawPolygon(vertices, 6, fillColor, 0.f, borderColor);
    _drawNode->setAnchorPoint(Point(0.5, 0.5));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
CCMenu  *myMenu =   CCMenu::create();
    myMenu->setPosition(CCPointZero);
    this->addChild(myMenu);

    int leftMargin  =   20;
    int topMargin   =   500;

    int index   =   0;
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        leftMargin  =   150;
        if (i%2 != 0) {
            leftMargin  =   leftMargin-(100/2);
        }
        for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {


            CCMenuItemImage *hexImg =   CCMenuItemImage::create("hexagon_new.png", "hexagon_new.png", this, menu_selector(Hexagon::clickOnHex));
            hexImg->setRotation(90);
            hexImg->setPosition(ccp(leftMargin, topMargin));
            hexImg->setTag(index);
            hexImg->setScale(115/hexImg->getContentSize().width);
            myMenu->addChild(hexImg);
            index++;
            leftMargin  += 100;
        }
        topMargin   -=  82;
    }
```

and the function to do animation on hexagon on user touch is -

```
void Hexagon::clickOnHex(CCObject *sender){
    CCMenuItemImage *tempHex    =   (CCMenuItemImage *)sender;
    CCRotateBy *rotateBy        =   CCRotateBy::create(0.5, 360);
    tempHex->runAction(rotateBy);
    CCLOG("HEX CLICKED");
}
```

do animation what you want.

this is the image that i used.

[hexagon image](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hexagon%20png&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=pzIpU9TCHsKprAfBpICIDA&sqi=2&ved=0CCUQsAQ&biw=1366&bih=596#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=9cacfH_45vbxtM%253A;PfbzJ3Wm9SdPUM;http%253A%252F%252Fimg-cache.cdn.gaiaonline.com%252F9e455b16d72b21999b3419a5cfbc92db%252Fhttp%253A%252F%252Fi41.photobucket.com%252Falbums%252Fe275%252FLord_Calo%252FHexagon.png;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.gaiaonline.com%252Fprofiles%252Fhexagon%252F6659613%252F;730;634)

Comment: But this way, isn't the image sprite having a rectangular touch space?

Comment: Yes, the image sprite will have a rectangular touch space by this way. but if the hexagon images are small than it wont hurt that much. And if you want perfectly haxagonal touch space. check for how to ignore touch on transparent part of image.This may help you http://cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/32722 I will also try to do this once i am free

Comment: The problem is that I need an Hexagon map like the imaged I attached to the question, so the white spaces of the images will overlap with each other. Anyway I will check the link for the transparent pixels code!